# Using binary search to find the duplicate number in an array

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

The problem:

Given an array of integers `nums` containing `n + 1` integers where each integer is in the range `[1, n]` inclusive.

There is only one repeated number in `nums`, return this repeated number.

You must solve the problem without modifying the array `nums` and uses only constant
extra space.

Here is one of the possible solution using binary search

```
class Solution(object):
    def findDuplicate(self, nums):
        beg, end = 1, len(nums)-1
        
        while beg + 1 <= end:
            mid, count = (beg + end)//2, 0
            for num in nums:
                if num <= mid: count += 1        
            if count <= mid:
                beg = mid + 1
            else:
                end = mid
        return end
```

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,3,4,2,2]
Output: 2
```

```
Example 2:

Input: nums = [3,1,3,4,2]
Output: 3
```

Can someone please explain this solution for me? I understand the code but I don't understand the logic behind this. In particular, I do not understand how to construct the if statements (lines 7 - 13). Why and how do you know that when `num <= mid` then I need to do `count += 1` and so on. Many thanks.

Comment: @fas I will provid more context. I apologise

Comment: attention binary search needs sorted inputs

Comment: No, I got it, it doesn't require array to be sorted. On each iteration we count number of elements that are less than `mid` and that's why it has `O(n log n)` complexity. Actually this is not the most optimal solution, you can get `O(n)` just by xor-ing all the numbers (and rounding up `n` to the nearest `2^x`).

Comment: `for num in nums` 100% defeats the purpose of binary search...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution keeps halving the range of numbers the answer can still be in.

For example, if the function starts with `nums == [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]`, then the duplicate number must be between `1` and `4` inclusive by definition.

By counting how many of the numbers are smaller than or equal to the middle of that range (`2`), you can decide if the duplicate must be in the upper or lower half of that range. Since the actual number is greater (3 numbers are lesser than or equal to 2, and 3 > 2), the number must be in the lower half.

Repeating the process, knowing that the number must be between `1` and `2` inclusive, only 1 number is less than or equal to the middle of that range (`1`), which means the number must be in the upper half, and is 2.

Consider a slightly longer series: `[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 7]`. Between 1 and 7 lies 3, 4 numbers are less than or equal to 3, so the number must be between 1 and 3. Between 1 and 3 lies 2, 2 numbers are less than or equal to 2, so the number must be over 2, which leaves 3.

The solution will iterate over all `n` elements of `nums` a limited number of times, since it keeps halving the search space. It's certainly more efficient than the naive:

```
    def findDuplicate(self, nums):
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            for j, m in enumerate(nums):
                if i != j and n == m:
                    return n
```

But as user @fas suggests in the comments, this is better:

```
    def findDuplicate(nums):
        p = 1
        while p < len(nums):
            p <<= 1
        r = 0
        for n in nums:
            r ^= n
        for n in range(len(nums), p):
            r ^= n
        return r
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how given binary search works. Inside binary search you have implementation of `isDuplicateLessOrEqualTo(x)`:

```
mid, count = (beg + end)//2, 0
for num in nums:
  if num <= mid: count += 1        
if count <= mid:
  return False  # In this case there are no duplicates less or equal than mid. 
                # Actually count == mid would be enough, count < mid is impossible.
else:
  return True   # In this case there is a duplicate less or equal than mid.
```

`isDuplicateLessOrEqualTo(x)` is a non-decreasing function (assume `x` has a duplicate, then for all `i < x` it's false and for all `i >= x` it's true), that's why you can run binary search over it.

Each iteration you run through the array, which gives you overall complexity `O(n log n)` (where `n` is size of array).

There's a faster solution. Note that `xor(0..(2^n)-1) = 0` for `n >= 2`, because there are `2^(n-1)` ones for each bit position and it's an even number, for example:

```
0_10 = 00_2
1_10 = 01_2
2_10 = 10_2
3_10 = 11_2
       ^
     2 ones here, 2 is even
        ^
      2 ones here, 2 is even
```

So by xor-ing all the numbers you'll receive exactly your duplicate number. Let's write it:

```py
class Solution(object):
  def nearestPowerOfTwo(number):
    lowerBoundDegreeOfTwo = number.bit_length()
    lowerBoundDegreeOfTwo = max(lowerBoundDegreeOfTwo, 2)
    return 2 ** lowerBoundDegreeOfTwo

  def findDuplicate(self, nums):
    xorSum = 0
    for i in nums:
      xorSum = xorSum ^ i
    for i in range(len(nums), nearestPowerOfTwo(len(nums) - 1)):
      xorSum = xorSum ^ i
    return xorSum
```

As you can see that gives us `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a different approach (not binary search) to solve this problem:

1. Sum all elements of the array - we will call it `sumArray` - the time complexity is O(n).
2. Sum all numbers from 1 to n (inclusive) - we will call it `sumGeneral` - this is simply (n * (n+1) / 2) - the time complexity is O(1).
3. Return the result of `sumArray - sumGeneral`

In total, the time complexity is O(n) (you cannot do better since you have to look at all elements of the array, potentially the repeated one is at the end), and additional space complexity is O(1).

(If you could use O(n) additional space complexity you could use a hash table)

Comment: "Sum all numbers from 1 to n ...  the time complexity is O(1)."
Depends on how you count. You perform calculations on large numbers, e.g. one digit number plus one digit number definitely works faster, that 100k digit number plus 100k digit number.